# CakePHP 2.4 - DB Update Doesn't Save All Passed Data One Field is Never Persisted

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I'm trying to update the DB using some data pulled from an external API.  The appstatus and amount both come from the same API, and I can see the values are correct, and they make it all the way down through the action to be updated, but when they are updated amount is not persisted while the other two are persisted in the DB.

```
$this->Application->create();
$this->Application->id = $appVal['Application']['id'];
$saved = $this->Application->save($app);
$this->Application->clear();
```

Data Contents of $app added to model with the correct record ID of 147

```
2015-07-02 22:23:42 Debug: DATA TO SAVE: Array
(
    [Application] => Array
        (
            [appstatus] => Approved
            [app_step] => 5
            [amount] => 13001
        )

)
```

Output from $saved after update of record ID 147:

```
2015-07-02 22:23:42 Debug: DATA THAT WAS SAVED: Array
(
    [Application] => Array
        (
            [appstatus] => Approved
            [user_status] => 2
            [app_step] => 5
            [amount_due] => 13001
            [modified] => 2015-07-02 22:23:42
        )

)
```

The appstatus, app_step, and modified values are all different in the database after an update, but the amount column is never persisted in the database and remains as 0 even though the update response indicates the amount to be 13001.

The migration used to add the amount column to the existing DB table looks okay, and I can see it in the DB:

```
ALTER TABLE  `applications` ADD  `amount_due` DOUBLE NOT NULL AFTER  `app_step`
```

I've looked through the [docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-save-array-data-null-boolean-validate-true-array-fieldlist-array), and when using create to update you should use clear(), but I tried it and it doesn't do anything.  Any ideas why this is not being persisted?

**UPDATE**

I can update any other field in the model just before it saves like: address, postalcode, amount, street_name, etc; and update them with no problem, but no what amount_due is never updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, CakePHP caches the models so the new field that was just added wasn't in the cache.  After blowing away the cache it all works as it should.  That is time I'll never get back, but that's the first thing I'll check from now on, so lesson learnt.